# PHP Symfony i18n disambiguation

Tags: php, localization, symfony1

How can we disambiguate homonyms in Symfony framework i18n?

It's when we have the same English word used for different meanings, and it should be translated to different words in different points. Like 'free' as in 'free beer' and as in 'free speech', and needs to be translated to different words in another language. Most scripts like Wordpress use contexts for this.

I'm considering using some IDs which include section names. I think using IDs is the right method for i18n anyway. However I think Symfony i18n doesn't support the usage of ID + defaults, like `__('ui:generic:yes','Yes')`. So I'm considering adding a dictionary for English including the IDs I need.

Any ideas for a more appropriate way (officially or widely accepted) to do this? Any best practices, samples, reference for Symfony i18n disambiguation / defaults / context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a very similar way in my apps : I use translation keys like this : homepage_main_title .
And I use a dictionary for English : this way, I can spot untranslated text even if I'm browsing the site in english.

Comment: Thanks greg. Do you know if Symfony i18n supports contexts through a parameter like Wordpress, eg. using 2 parameters like ('comment','noun')? That's also a good way for working with translators, making it easier for them to translate a word.

Comment: I think context is handled depending on where you are in the app : if you are in a template of the 'article' module, the i18n file of this module will have the priority over the other i18n files. But I don't think you can specify a given context manually, that's why I'm putting it in the translation key.

Answer (score 0):

A proper way to do this with Symfony is to use the catalogues.

```
<?php
  echo __('your message',array(),'catalogname');
?>
```